# Which would be the Koppen-Geiger climate distribution of this map?

Tags: science-based, climate, weather, alternate-reality, map-making

[image]

The existence of closed seas makes it difficult to me, especially the East one. I have it clear that in the souteast region the climate would be influenced by monzoon, but if the world has only one continent would the movement of the Intertropical Convergence Zone be very pronounced over the year? It would affect also the west side of the map? In which way? The map doesn't show it but the north of the continent is like 2500km longer westward, but the bigger part of it is above the 50º latitude anyway.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to know the vegetation of your world in order to determine this? Or are you trying to have the distribution so that you can know the kinds of vegetation to go where?

Comment: The climates determine the vegetation, bro. Vegetation will be decided later.

Comment: Nice map. If this planet has a civilization, there would probably be someone who takes the initiative to go dig a canal, to connect the two oceans.. Panama canal squared ! This term "Köppen Geiger" (mind the umlaut and the e) I had to google https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification